# How to handle a question that is being edited to make a new question?

Tags: discussion

The question [how to retrieve or search user from as400 using ldap connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22189456/58061) has been edited many times and the original poster is continuing to use the same question to ask new questions.

I have voted to close and flagged for moderator attention.

What is the proper procedure to handle this type of activity?